# WPF SelectedItem working inconsistently....(MVVM data binding)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF ListBox that is a child of a ListView.

The ListBox has a 'SelectedItem' attribute that is bound to a property on my ViewModel **SelectedTask**.

When I click a row on my ListBox, then it updates **SelectedTask**.  But only sometimes.....

By sometimes:

- Every List Box row will update **SelectedTask** at least once
- The ones in the "middle" of the screen will always update **SelectedTask**.  I can hop from one row to another and back again, each time **SelectedTask** is updated
- The ones at the top or bottom of the screen will update **SelectedTask**, but maybe only once.  If I select another row and then return to this one, I can not get **SelectedTask** to be updated.

A highly cut-down/edited view of my XAML is as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding WorkItems}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="850"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            /* Display properties from Work Item */
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Code}" />

                            /* This SelectedItem works sometimes, but not all the time */
                            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedTask, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                /* Display properties from Work Item  Task */
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"  />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**EDIT**
I was asked what the **SelectedTask** property looked like:

```
public MyTaskType SelectedTask
{
    get { return _selectedTask; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTask = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `SelectedTask` property from the view-model look like?

Comment: @Bradley: Good question, I'll edit the post and add that information in.

Comment: What happens if you change the setter to `set
    { if(_selectedTask != value){
        _selectedTask = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();}
    }` so that notification only happens if the value is different.  I'm thinking what you are seeing might be related to cascading property change notifications due to having multiple controls bound to the same property.  This is generally a good pattern to follow anyway.

Comment: @Bradley: Modified as suggested, no change.  I'm not convinced that I even need the `NotifyPropertyChanged()`, the `SelectedItem` is pushing data, not pulling it, but I got the same behaviour when I removed it.

Comment: Ah - I've just figured what the problem is.  Each ListView row has its own ListBox.  So, if ListView Row 1's ListBox has 5 entries, I can continually hop from one ListBox entry to another.  However, ListView Row 2's ListBox is a completely different entity, so selecting a row has no effect on the selected row of any other ListBox.  The problem I encountered was when a ListBox had only one item....I couldn't re-select it (as it was still selected).  Looks like I need to re-think this.  Are there any established patterns for this?

Comment: I have temporarily fixed the behaviour, but it's certainly not elegant.  In my XAML ListBox, I add `PreviewMouseUp` which is handled by the XAML's code-behind file which, up to now, had been satisfyingly empty.  The code-behind can access the ViewModel, and so my event handler updates the **SelectedTask** property from the `sender` object.  Would be happy to hear of a more elegant suggestion that doesn't use the code behind file....

Comment: Ahhh, that's what I was referring to as a property change Cascade, but I assumed each listbox was identical, and you purposely bounded them all to the same property. The ideal mvvm way to fix it would be to have the selected item bound to a property on its own Row's view model, which communicates back to the parent via reference if needed. I can show you an example when I get to a computer, I'm on a phone right now, and typing sucks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155027/discussion-between-drgriff-and-bradley-uffner).

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow chat doesn't work through the firewall at my workplace.